# How do I properly set cross-domain cookies with SameSite None and Secure?

Tags: javascript, jsp, cookies, websecurity

I inherited a website to maintain.  It uses two different third-party programs and transfers information between the two using an iFrame to set cookies.  The information is not particularly sensitive.

Using generic versions of everything, let's say:
* Tool 1:  www.xyzWarehouse.com
* Tool 2:  www.xyzCorp.com
* In-between page:  tools.xyzCorp.com

1. xyzWarehouse opens a tiny iFrame for tools.xyzCorp.com/setTransferCookies.jsp
2. setTransferCookies.jsp sets cookies for domain xyzCorp.
3. xyzWarehouse then runs a black box that opens the URL for the correct page of xyzCorp
4. custom JS code on xyzCorp then opens those cookies and uses them to pre-fill form fields.

I've recently been trying to update the cookies to account for changes in browser security requirements.  At the moment, my current problem is in trying to get cookies to work for Chrome, using SameSite:None and Secure.

Long-term, we want to have all three locations to look like:
* www.xyzWarehouse.com
* corp.xyzWarehouse.com
* tools.xyzWarehouse.com

But that has to go through red tape with IT and involves changes on the administrator for tool1 and tool2.  We need an intermediate solution to keep us going until then.

This is what I've tried:

Original code 1:  Using .jsp

```
cookieString = cookieString.substring(0,cookieString.length()-1) + "}";
Cookie cookie = new Cookie ("xyzTracking",cookieString);
cookie.setMaxAge(365 * 24 * 60 * 60);
cookie.setDomain("xyzWarehouse.com");
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

I can't seem to find a version of Cookies which involves samesite, so probably can't use this.  Please let me know if I'm wrong.  This, of course, gives an error telling me I need to use SameSite: None

Attempt 2:  Using JavaScript

```
for (i=0;i<attPairs.length;i++) {
    var pair = attPairs[i].split("=");
    params[pair[0]] = pair[1];
}
jQuery.cookies.set( 'xyzTracking', params, {expiresAt: date, domain:'xyzWarehouse.com', sameSite: 'None', secure: 'true'});
```

Chrome complained - errors about samesite.

Attempt 3:  Using JavaScript

```
for (i=0;i<attPairs.length;i++) {
    var pair = attPairs[i].split("=");
    params[pair[0]] = pair[1];
}
document.cookie = "xyzTracking=" + encodeURIComponent(params) + "; domain=xyzWarehouse.com; SameSite=None; Secure";
```

Chrome complained - errors about samesite

Attempt 4:  Using .jsp

```
cookieString = cookieString.substring(0,cookieString.length()-1) + "}";
response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "xyzTracking="+cookieString+"; SameSite=none; Secure; Domain=xyzWarehouse.com");
```

Chrome will let this run without reporting any errors, but on the far side, trying to retrieve cookies, www.xyzWarehouse.com tells me that there are no cookies set.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?  I do not have any experience in .jsp, I have a lot of experience in JavaScript, but honestly I try to program to avoid using cookies if at all possible, so I have barely ever had to set them.  Those I have set were never cross-domain.